# In Java, Storing String

Tags: java, string

I have a question about storing string in java.
You know that I can store strings using a String class or a character array, but we normally use String  class to store string. But Why do you store string in String object as opposed to using character array for storage. As I know, other low-level languages strings are stored as character array.

Could you explain the reason and the advantage of using String object to store strings?

Thank you.

Comment: Java *isn't* a low-level language?

Comment: I know that but I am just curious about why java uses string object to store string, not character array.

Comment: It *does* use a character array. Inside the `String` class.

Comment: In Java, even an array is a type of `Object`. Plus, if it was stored as a `char[]` it would be more difficult to optimize with the `String` pool.

Comment: **Other** low level languages. Interesting. Please name a _high_ level language... P.S. give me an array that has an `endsWith` method.

Comment: `String` object immutable instead of `char[]`, also has useful wrapper functions over internal `char[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look for String implementation in java and you'll see something like:

`private final char value[];`

which means that String uses a character array.
Quote from documentation:

`The class String includes methods for examining individual characters of the sequence, for comparing strings, for searching strings, for extracting substrings, and for creating a copy of a string with all characters translated to uppercase or to lowercase.`

So you see that String contains also useful methods for operations on String and we can tell that using String class is just the most convenient way to store strings.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Javadoc it explains it well:

> Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are
>   created. String buffers support mutable strings. Because String
>   objects are immutable they can be shared. For example:
>
> ```
>  String str = "abc";
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
>  char data[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
>  String str = new String(data);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There is one significant difference between `String`s and `char[]` - when it comes to security it is much better to use array of `char`s because `String`s are immutable and you cannot change them.

It leads to situation where you cannot override e.g. password which has been stored somewhere in the memory and anyone who can access this memory is able to read such password.

If you use `char[]` then after using password you can *clean* the array.